# C++ Code::Blocks program causes blue screen when run from command line

Tags: c++, mingw, blue-screen-of-death

I was using Code::Blocks to try out parallel programming using OpenMP. MinGW compiler included in original Code::Blocks folder didn't support OpenMP, so I downloaded newer version (7.0.0) from Sourceforge and set up the project accordingly (-fopen parameter, path to libgomp-1.dll) and everything seemed to work as expected. Program is compiled and runs without problems when launched in Code::blocks. But when I tried to launch the .exe file from command line, I end up with Blue screen of death. The same thing happens with any code, even "hello world". Original MinGW given with Code::Blocks doesn't have this problem. I also tried another version (8.1.0) with the same result. It seems the crash happens even before any command from main function is performed. Using Win 7 64bit.

Comment: Your whole computer bluescreens?

Comment: Yes, total bluescreen followed by OS boot